# Can anyone tell me why I can't edit a plugin when it is installed without having to re-install?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, functions, theme-development

I am using a shortcode plugin as a framework for the short codes I want to add that go with my theme. I decided to just include the plugin in a repo for the user to dl so I am not building theme right into the theme.

When I try to add shortcodes, and make changes they don't seem to show up no matter what I do unless I reinstall the plugin completely.

I am using Notepad++ as an editor instead of the WP editor, because I can't see why it would matter. This seems to happen with any plugin I attempt to modify. What gives?

Comment: I edit "live" plugins all the time (on a dev server). Whatever is happening has something to do with how you have this setup, and I can't tell exactly what you've done.

Comment: When checking the editor, it appears that only a few of the plugin files are being displayed. My guess is that it must be some kind of permission error. Although I changed all the dirs and files in the plugin folder to 777.

Comment: Your question states that you are using Notepad++. In your comment you are asking about the built in editor. The editor is very limited. It does not show files inside folders, for one.

Comment: Yes I am using notepad++ but I checked to see if the files were visible. I did not know that. I figured it was the same as the theme editor and showed all of the php files in all directories. Actually come to think of it, the files appearing in the plugin editor are in a directory within the plugins main directory.